# html scrolling: jump to end of page (horizontal) w/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Is there a script that will jump the page to the horizontal end.

A user can press "Home" and "End" on the keyboard to jump to the top and bottom of the webpage, but what about right and left?

How do I spare the user of the inconvenience of having to scroll to the far, far depths of the x scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizontal scroll is a somehow unfrequent situation, as naturally the browser will try to vertical scroll unless unresizable elements really overflow the visible area; I will thus assume you are more in an explicitly-horizontal design such as one of these: http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/40-of-the-best-horizontal-scrolling-websites

In any case, the basic is the same: catch some key* event, and do what you want.

Catch the event and launch your scroll function:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', scrollfct, true);
```

First caveat: 'keypress' will not catch special characters such as up/down etc., so use 'keydown' or 'keyup'

Now the scroll function:

```
function scrollfct(e) {
   console.log(evt.keyCode); /* this will debug that your function is being called, and will help you get the keyCodes you want. Remove in production :-) */
   var HOME_LEFT = 33; //HOME
   var HOME_RIGHT = 34; //END
   if (e.keyCode == HOME_LEFT) {
       window.scroll(0,0);
   };
   if (e.keyCode == HOME_RIGHT) {
       window.scroll(document.body.scrollWidth,0);
   }
}
```

For window.scroll doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scroll

Second caveat: to be fully cross-browser, you'll have to do some homework.

If you want to deal with mousewheel too, or want some smooth scroll, check this out: http://paulicio.us/items/view/24/horizontal-page-scrolling-using-javascript or with jQuery: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/ OR just use HTML5 CSS Transitions.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd say, pagination would save the user from scrolling all over the place, but there are a couple other techniques. You could include a "right" button that links to the ID of something at the right of the page. That would jump them there immediately. That would look like this

```
<a href="#overtotheright">Goto the Right</a>
. . .
<div id="overtotheright"> . . . </div>
```

Or in javascript, the following should work.

```
window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollWidth, 0);
```

Comment: should that be scrollWidth? (since @dany wants the horizontal end of page)

Comment: I just saw that, changed the code. Now that I'm thinking about it, @dany probably wants to catch the home and end key events to perform the scrolling.